# Android Studio - Connection refused: connect

Tags: android-studio

I got a new laptop and after installing Android Studio, the gradle build fails with Connection refused: connect error, android studio unable to resolve dependency,Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4. etc.

The gradle services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.2-bin.zip downloads succesfully but the build fails. Tried:

- Reinstalling
- Setting proxy via Astrill VPN
- Disabling proxy
- Downloading gradle manually
- Closing VPN
- Invalidating Cache/Restart
- Searched all available solution short of reinstalling windows

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: You don't need to reinstall windows. It seems like a network error, and all you can do is just get a good connection.

Comment: Thanks mate, I finally figured it out; Windows defender blocked it, when I turned it off it worked 

Comment: @SevenWinds instead of adding "Fixed" to your question title, add your resolution information in an answer to this question, and then accept it (when you're able - for self-answered questions it takes 2 days.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days of wondering in the deserts of the web, I've managed to find something that could help me and hopefully will help you.

Windows 11, Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 4

The solution to this connection issue is to set the proxy to YOUR proxy and force use of Http instead of Https (not sure about this one as it was added at the same time):

Steps:

1. Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Update Sites > Tick the box at the bottom with "Force https://...."
2. Open Windows settings > Network & Internet > Proxy > Manual Proxy Setup > Click on Edit

In the Proxy IP Address copy the address and the port (Looks something like = ip 128.0.0.1, port 3212)

3. Back to Android Studio > File > Settings > HTTP Proxy > Set Manual proxy configuration to credentials from step 2 > Click ok
4. Build your project and pray it works.

Thank you!